# Quickblox 1:1 Video Conferencing javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, video-streaming

I have downloaded the JavaScript sdk from Quickblox site but I am unable to run it on my local machine. I am new to node.js. I go through the code and do not found any main.js file. I am not getting the correct steps to setup my JavaScript sdk. Please Help me out with examples and steps to run my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

[You can check step by step process here](http://quickblox.com/developers/5_Minute_Guide#Launch_the_Javascript_Chat_code_sample)  to run code in your local machine.

For More Detail About Javascript SDK You Can Check [This Link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript)